# Basic filtering of data based on user & item in Python SciKit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I am trying to implement a recommender system to users based on their rating. I think the most common one. I was reading alot and shortlisted  Surprise, a python-scikit based recommender systems.

While am able to import data and run prediction, its not exactly as I would want it.

**Right now what I have:** I can pass a user_id, item_id and rating and get the probability of that user giving the rating I passed.

**What I really want to do:** Pass a user_id and in return get a list of items that would be potentially liked/rated highly by that user based on the data.

```
from surprise import Reader, Dataset    
from surprise import SVD, evaluate

# Define the format
reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating timestamp', sep='\t')
# Load the data from the file using the reader format
data = Dataset.load_from_file('./data/ecomm/e.data', reader=reader)    

# Split data into 5 folds
data.split(n_folds=5)

algo = SVD()

# Retrieve the trainset.
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
algo.fit(trainset)

//Inputs are: user_id, item_id & rating.
print algo.predict(3, 107, 1)
```

**Sample lines from data file.**

> First column is user_id, 2nd is item id, 3rd is rating and then timestamp.

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
298 474 4   884182806
115 265 2   881171488
253 465 5   891628467
305 451 3   886324817
6   86  3   883603013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through all possible `item_id`  values for a single `user_id` and predict its rating. Then you collect the highest rated items to recommend to that user.

But make sure that the `user_id`, `item_id` pair is not in the training dataset. Something like [this function here](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trainset.html#surprise.Trainset.build_anti_testset):

> **build_anti_testset**
>
> Return a list of ratings that can be
>   used as a testset in the test() method.
>
> The ratings are all the ratings that are not in the trainset, i.e. all
>   the ratings rui where the user u is known, the item i is known, but
>   the rating rui is not in the trainset. As rui is unknown, it is either
>   replaced by the fill value or assumed to be equal to the mean of all
>   ratings global_mean.

After that you can pass these pairs to the `test()` or `predict()` method and collect the ratings, and get the top N recommendations from this data for a particular user.

An example of this is given here:

- https://blog.dominodatalab.com/recommender-systems-collaborative-filtering/